# Liferay 6.2: Documents and Media portlet subscription feature not working for standard user

Tags: plugins, liferay, portlet, liferay-6, subscription

I am using Liferay 6.2 and want to set the options for the folder subscription feature in the Documents and Media portlet. My problem is that the button "subscribe" only appears for my Admin-user. For every other user of my portal it is not showing up.

I checked every permission that is set for users in the portal and the subscription-feature is nowhere to be seen. How can I have my normal users subscribe to folders?

Where can I find the right settings?

TIA

Comment: That is strange I just check in my Liferay 6.2 instance a user with default User & Power User role is able to view the subscribe button for folders & files and able to subscribe. He is non-admin user. I have not changed any thing in the roles for document and media portlet. For checking person see the roles that are assigned to your user and got to define permission for user role and try to update subscribe permission to see if it works ? and also from Configuration >  Server Administration do the database clean-ups. If that helps.

Comment: All of the users have an own role that I created. Everyone of them has the same permissions as the "Site-Member" and "Power-User" role.

Comment: do they *only* have the custom role that you've created or also the standard *User* role?

Comment: of course they have both :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

The problem was that the users were not assigned to the open site. Although they had all the roles they needed they HAD to be assigned to the site, not only the community.